# UINavigationController instantiated in AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I just started learning iOS development. I've seen example code that creates a ViewController class for the sole purpose of initiating a UINavigationController, as shown below. What is the benefit of that, vs just creating a UINavigationController in the AppDelegate, and assigning it to self.window.rootViewController, as in snippet 2:

snippet1:

```
MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mvc] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

snippet2:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navigation view controller manages other view controllers, providing the interface for a  stack-like structure to navigate through an application. If you just create a navigation controller without any view controllers to manage, it will have nothing to do or display.  It might even cause an error (I haven't specifically tried it).

Comment: so, am I effectively setting a default view controller to be managed by UINavigationController in snippet1? If so, when I want to switch to another view, do I manage that inside MyViewController.m or do I manage that inside AppDelegate didFinishWithLaunchOptions, where I created navController?

Comment: You beat me to it. The navigation view controller has its own root view controller and would likely result in a bad memory access error if you don't set its root view controller.

Comment: @Mr. Will - so, since UIWindow has a root view controller property, and typically there is only one instance of UIWindow (at least at this point in my learning), does UINavigationController essentially take over for UIWindow? So, you push and pop views onto the UINavigationController instance, and never worry about adding / removing views directly to UIWindow?

Comment: Each UIViewController has a 'navigationController' property that you can use to "push" or "pop" view controllers from the stack.  You would do this somewhere in the MyViewController.m : [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES]

Comment: >" never worry about adding / removing views directly to UIWindow?"

Generally speaking, yes.  Most applications do not need to worry about UIWindow (after launching), and working with UIWindow usually means that you want to have more fine-tuned control over specific kinds of touch events, not that you simply want to change from one view controller to another.  Adding subviews directly to UIWindow can have some side-effects, like rotation not working as you would expect, so you generally want to avoid doing it if you can.

Comment: OK one last clarification - is there any difference in the "state of the view stack", for lack of a better term, between, say pushing 3 different views onto the stack from MyViewController.m, vs pushing V2 from MyViewController, pushing V3 from V2, pushing V4 from V3, etc.?

Comment: I think that the actual data contained in the stack would be the same, but the usual pattern is to push V3 from V2, V4 from V3.  I have never tried to push more than one view controller at a time, so I am not sure exactly what would happen, but I expect it might be a little bit jarring from a user interface perspective.